# Why can't I use fill down in OO Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I cannot use Ctrl+D in Calc. It grayed out, disabled. Look at the image.

[image]

And there are just test numbers I wanted to fill down.

[image]

Can somebody help? The same is in LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select **at least two cells** before the `Fill -> Down` functionality will be available. Details depend on your use case:

- If you want to make Calc **continue a series of numbers**, you'll have to select the last two cells, in your case: `B6:B7`. Now you can select the fill function, or you can drag down the box with the thick black border to fill the selected cells.
- If you cant to **copy a static content quickly** to the adjacent cells, you have to select the cell containing the static content (a string, for example) **and** some adjacent cells. If you select `Fill...` -> `Down` from Menu `Edit`, Calc will copy the static string in all the selected cells.

Comment: So this Ctrl+D is not the same as Excel's Ctrl+D (copies the cell above)?

Comment: I assume it isn't the same (but i can't tell for sure since i don't use excel). In every case, Calc requires the selection of **more than one cell** before AutoFill (CTRL+D) is available. If you have more than one cell selected (including the cell holding the value to copy), it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do a fill down is to select the last already-filled cell (e.g., B7, not B8 in your example) and extend the selection to as far down as you want it to go.

See if it works then.

It appears you are selecting an empty cell and that is not working.

There is a special case where you select the cell to fill with only.  I believe it will then fill one more cell in the specified direction.  I've never gotten in the habit of using that.

Comment: I know this. I do not need this feature. I need a Ctrl+D like in Excel which copies the cell above

Answer (score 0):

If you want the formula to be propagated down to all rows, you can press ctrl + double click on the lower right corner of the cell and it'll be filled in all of the rows in that column.

Comment: can you explain this? i cannot make it work.